# Why is this returning a string instead of an object?

Tags: python

I have a graph and a node class. In a method, I create a new node for a graph; then I call one of that node's attributes: 'daughters'. I receive an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'daughters'`, in response to the line `for daughter in currentNode.daughters`.
Why is there a string as currentNode, instead of a Node object?

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.node_list = {}
        self.number = 0
        self.names = []

    def node(self, node_name):
        if node_name in self.node_list:
            return self.node_list[node_name
        else:
            self.node_list[node_name] = Node()
            return self.node_list[node_name]
         ....

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.daughters = []
    ...


def PrefixTrieConstruction(patterns):
    trie = Graph()
    trie.node('root')

    for pattern in patterns:
        currentNode = trie.node('root')
        for symbol in pattern:
            for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
                if daughter.label == symbol:
                    currentNode = daughter
                    break
            else:
                node_name = trie.name_node()
                trie.node(node_name)
                trie.edge(currentNode, node_name, symbol)
                currentNode = node_name
    return trie
```

Comment: You are assigning in 3 different places to `currentNode`, one of them seems suspect ...

Comment: If currentNode.daughters is a list of strings instead of a list of objects, that could cause the problem you describe. Where are you populating that list?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Yes, I had a bad assignment to currentNode. Thanks very much.